# Entity Framework updating entry with related entries only updates main entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Situation: my `Main` class looks like this:

```
class Main 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

My `Customer` class looks like this:

```
class Customer 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public EMail Email { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: I was reading that it is better to use the context as short as possible with using syntax. So I take the main class out of the Database, let it change the props and will then update the main class.

The problem is that my related entries are all duplicates. I have tried several suggestions:

First approach:

```
private object InsertOrUpdate<T, TKey>(T entity, Func<T, TKey>  idExpression) where T : class
{       
  var existingEntity = LokaleContext.Set<T>().Find(idExpression(entity));
  if (existingEntity != null)
  {
    if (LokaleContext.Entry(existingEntity).State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
      LokaleContext.Set<T>().Attach(existingEntity);
    }
    else
    {
      LokaleContext.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    }

    return existingEntity;
  }
  else
  {
    LokaleContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    return entity;
  }
}
```

I used this code to return the related entries and couple them back to the main class.

For example:

```
var customerFromDb = db.Set<Costumer>()
                       .Include(c => c.Address)
                       .Include(c => c.EMail)
                       .Include(c => c.Language)
                       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == customerUsedLocal.Id);
customerUsedLocal.Customer.Address = InsertOrUpdate(customerFromDb.Customer.Address, a => a.Id);
```

I repeated this for `Language` and `EMail` classes.

After that I map the two classes;

```
MapObject(CustomerLoca, CustomerFromDb);
public object MapObject<T>(T entitySource, T entityDestination) where T : class
{
  var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<T, T>(); });
  IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
  return mapper.Map(entitySource, entityDestination);
}
```

and finally I set the state of the `CustomerFromDb` to modified.

But whatever I try to do, nothing is working, I tried all these links without any result :-(

[OptimisticConcurrencyException when persisting related entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886879/optimisticconcurrencyexception-when-persisting-related-entry)

[Entity Framework not updating existing related entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116341/entity-framework-not-updating-existing-related-entity)

[Finding updated entry with Entity Framework Timestamp using code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279614/finding-updated-entry-with-entity-framework-timestamp-using-code-first)

[Entity Framework Updating with Related Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612655/entity-framework-updating-with-related-entity)

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it, I was confused about the examples given and muddle things.
So here is my solution
first I create a mapper configuration file

```
public class AutoMapperConfigurator:Profile
{

    public AutoMapperConfigurator()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, Customer>()
            .ForMember(v=>v.Id, opt=>opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(v=>v.Address,opt=>opt.Ignore())
            ;
    }
}
```

After that I go to the repository and do the following code:

```
//Get customer from db
var CustomerFromDb= LokaleContext.Set<Customer>().Include(c=>c.Address).FirstOrDefault(k => k.Id == Customer.Id);
//Couple the configfile to automapper
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperConfigurator>();});
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
//Map the two objects
        var CustomerforDb= mapper.Map(Customer, CustomerFromDb);
        //Get the address from the Db and couple it to the newly coupled      //entrie
        CustomerforDb.Address= LokaleContext.Set<Address>().SingleOrDefault(k=>k.Id==LichaamsBouw.Klant.Id);

        //save in db.
        LokaleContext.SaveChanges();
```